# regex for matching abc.com & abc.com/.*

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to write a regex which matches all the below inputs

```
www.abc.com
www.abc.com/xyz_first
www.abc.com/xyz_second
www.abc.com/xyz_third
www-test.abc.com
www-test.abc.com/xyz_first
www-test.abc.com/xyz_second
www-test.abc.com/xyz_third
```

The domain name is www.abc.com. I have the following here but it does not work for me. I need to match the above inputs

```
var exp = /.*\/xyz_first || xyz_second || xyz_third ||  \/.*/;
```

Comment: Have you tried to read the documentation? Doing it would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `/^www(?:-test)?\.abc\.com(?:\/(?:xyz_first|xyz_second|xyz_third))?$/`

```js
var inputs = [
  'www.abc.com',
  'www.abc.com/xyz_first',
  'www.abc.com/xyz_second',
  'www.abc.com/xyz_third',
  'www-test.abc.com',
  'www-test.abc.com/xyz_first',
  'www-test.abc.com/xyz_second',
  'www-test.abc.com/xyz_third'
];

var regex = /^www(?:-test)?\.abc\.com(?:\/(?:xyz_first|xyz_second|xyz_third))?$/;

for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ )
{
  console.log( inputs[i], regex.test( inputs[i] ) );
}
```

Comment: no I don't want it to match www.abc.com/xyz_fourth. It basically should match just the above inputs and nothing other than that

Comment: You failed to mention that in the question... answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following regex,

```
www.?-?(\w+)*.abc.com
```

[Working Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pA7qT8/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: www(.|-)\w*.\w*.com([/]\w*)?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the part you're actually looking for is just a switch of specific values as the switch you're showing has the syntax for that very incorrect.

You can do that like this:

```
/\/(xyz_first|xyz_second|xyz_third)/
```

I think you are trying to use || as an 'or' but that's not how regexes work. You use a single pipe `|` as an OR, but its an OR global to the scope, so you need to scope with parenthesis unless you mean this or everything else.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Given your original regex, it looks like you want to match any of those listed above as long as they contain `xyz_` followed by one of the words: `first`,`second`, or `third` (but as per your comments to @MT0, not `fourth`, etc.).

The regex `.*\/(xyz_first|xyz_second|xyz_third)(\/.*)?` will match any domain (`abc.com` as well as `www-test.abc.com` or `example.com`). But it then allows the `/` and everything after it to be optional.

You can see this in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/zI7iQ2/1).

That means that you get:

```
www.abc.com                    (no match)
www.abc.com/xyz_first          (match)
www.abc.com/xyz_second         (match)
www.abc.com/xyz_third          (match)
www.abc.com/xyz_fourth         (match)
www-test.abc.com               (no match)
www-test.abc.com/xyz_first     (match)
www-test.abc.com/xyz_second    (match)
www-test.abc.com/xyz_third     (match)
www-test.abc.com/xyz_fourth    (match)
```

If this is not what you intended, be sure to update your original question to reflect what you want (and don't want) to match as specifically as possible.